# Mongodb expressjs Removing one object inside array by ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Removing object inside array using

this is my data in mongodb

[image]

```
   exports.trythis = (req,res) => {
  compagne.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: "60d9ef555d051400157414ce" },
    { $pull: { adsets    : { _id :  "617dd41faa3bc54b08a5547f" } } },
    { new: true }
  )
    .then(templates => { res.json(templates);})
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

i need to delete the adset with object id  for the array of compagnes  1 to many relation

thank your help

Answer (score 0):

`$pull` by `ObjectId("617dd41faa3bc54b08a5547f")`

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "1"
},
{
  $pull: {
    adsets: ObjectId("617dd41faa3bc54b08a5547f")
  }
},
{
  new: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vpBUWdfguLp)